# dotnetnuke right module bleed in firefox/chrome

Tags: dotnetnuke

http://www.dutchlandrollers.com/Sponsors/OurSponsors/tabid/105/Default.aspx

The right module overlaps the content one in Firefox/Chrome displays fine in IE. I'm not much of a DNN maven, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Taht is almost certainly a skin/css issue, not anything particular to do with DNN.  You will have better luck asking about the css layout techniques that are being used.

Comment: Yeah - that's not a bad idea. I don't know if I can edit the skin from the DNN admin tab; I don't have access to the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the original skin installation package to edit locally on your computer in a text editor or something like Visual Web Developer Express.  It's definitely the css that is the problem.  Both with the menu items and with the right column content alignment.  You could try using Firebug for Firefox to help narrow down the problem css, but adding 20px to the contentpane width worked.  The css looks rather unconventional or non-standards to me, though.  I'd probably have done it a bit differently in general.

It looks like your DNN install is an older version about two years old.  You should try the skin out with the latest version of DNN - upgrading will enhance your security as older sites are speculated to be the targets of widespread hacking attempts using asp.net security bugs that were recently addressed by both microsoft and dnn's latest version 5.5.1.  The important one really is the microsoft updates, so make sure your host is keeping current on security upgrades.  And again, I'd try out the dnn upgrade locally first before attempting an upgrade on your server, and make backups first, too.

You would also likely need host/superuser account access to install your edited version of the skin on your live server.  If you'd like help, I may be able to do the edits for you, but I would charge $15/hour to do so, and would require at least a temporary host user account.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll see what the site admins would like to do.

Comment: re: the recent asp.net padding oracle security issue.  When all is said and done all DNN versions (and many many asp.net websites of all types) are vulnerable unless the MS released patches are applied on the servers.  It turned out that the mitigation steps suggested by MS and included in 5.5.1 did NOT fix the issue.  Newer versions of DNN do address other security issues, but that one REQUIRES the MS patch to resolve.

Comment: Also you should be able to edit the skin files directly.  They will be in Portals/_default/Skins if installed at host level, or Portals/x/Skins if installed at Admin level.